# Specify fixed parameters and parameters to be search in optuna (lightgbm)

Tags: python-3.x, lightgbm, optuna

I just found Optuna and it seems they are integrated with lightGBM, but I struggle to see where I can fix parameters, e.g `scoring="auc"` and where I can define a gridspace to search, e.g `num_leaves=[1,2,5,10]`.

Using https://github.com/optuna/optuna/blob/master/examples/lightgbm_tuner_simple.py as example, they just define a `params` dict with some fixed parameters (are all parameters not specified in that dict tuned?), and the [documentation](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.integration.lightgbm.train.html#optuna.integration.lightgbm.train) states that

*It tunes important hyperparameters (e.g., min_child_samples and feature_fraction) in a stepwise manner*

How can I controll which parameters are tuned and in what space, and how can I fix some parameters?

Answer (score 3):

I have no knowledge of LightGBM, but since this is the first result for fixing parameters in optuna, I'll answer that part of the question:

In optuna, the search space is defined within the code of the objective function. This function should take a 'trials' object as an input, and you can create parameters by calling the `suggest_float()`, `suggest_int()` etc. functions on that trials object. For more information, see the documentation at [10_key_features/002_configurations.html](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/10_key_features/002_configurations.html)

Generally, fixing a parameter is done by hardcoding it instead of calling a `suggest` function, but it is possible to fix specific parameters externally using the  [PartialFixedSampler](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.samplers.PartialFixedSampler.html)